# Azure LogicApp for migration of millions of files

Tags: azure, migration, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage, data-migration

**I have the following requirements, where I consider using Azure LogicApp:**

- Files placed in Azure Blob Storage must be migrated into a custom place (it can be different from case to case)
- Amount of files is something about 1 000 000
- When the process is over, we should have a report saying how many records (files) failed
- If the process stopped somewhere in the middle, the next run must take only files that have not been migrated
- The process must be fast as it can be and files must be migrated within N hours

But what makes me worried is the fact that I cannot find any examples or articles (including official Azure Documentation) where the same thing is achieved by Azure LogicApp.

**I have some ideas about my requirements and Azure Logic App:**

1. I think that I must use pagination for dealing with this amount of files because Azure Logic App will not be able to read millions of file names - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exceed-default-page-size-with-pagination
2. I can add a record into Azure Table Storage to track failed migrations (something like creating a record to say that the process started and updating it when the file is moved to the destination)
3. I have no ideas how I can restart the Azure Logic App without using a custom tracking mechanism (for instance it can be the same Azure Table Storage instance)
4. And the question about splitting the work across several units is still open

Do you think that Azure Logic App is the right choice for my needs or I should consider something else? If Azure LogicApp can work for me, could you please share your thoughts and ideas on how I can achieve the given requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think logic app is a good solution for you to implement the requirement because the amount of files is about 1000000, that's too much. For this requirement, I suggest you to use Azure Data Factory.

To migrate data in azure blob according data factory, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage)